# Rank on Filtered cell

Tags: excel, vba

thank you so much for all of the user in stack overflow! I learned a lot

I have one problem with Rank on filtered cell with in the group. Below is what I want.
I want rank them after filtered.
Is there any code that I can use to rank them when it filtered? rank on visible cells only.
Because I want to see the rank after I filtered with Requirement

Many thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
Try this, it should work if above table starts at "A1"

```
Sub Filter_AND_Sort()

    ' Filters on the value "TRUE" in the fourth column (field=4)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$15").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="TRUE"

    ' In this newely created filter we are sorting now
    ' First remove any possible previous sorting
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ' New sorting criteria are entered, sorting column C => ("C1:C15")
    ' sorting on value lowest on top, highest below => SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("C1:C15"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

    ' Now we apply these new sorting criteria on the full table
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```